# How to protect directory from being accessed from php?

Tags: php, apache, include

I have got directories like `/www/site1` and `/www/site2` on my server. I would like to prevent files in `site1` from executing things like:

```
include("../site2/configuration.php");
```

I need the directories to be completely independent.

Answer (score 2):

Run PHP [as a user other then the web server user](https://serverfault.com/questions/264760/how-to-run-php-with-the-user-permission-on-apache) and set the permissions on the directories and files so they can only be access by the owner (`chmod 700`).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [open_basedir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir) php.ini directive.

Comment: As I understand it, it's just a global list of dirs that can be accessed, isn't it? I need something to assign locally, that any file in `/www/site1/*` can access only `/www/site1/*`, `/www/site2/*` only `/www/site2/*` and so on...

Comment: You can define open_basedir for each virtual host separatly.